# Jquery Mobile non breaking spaces/characters being inserted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile to create an application and I'm getting a weird problem. 
Between my homepage's listview this is being displayed

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

without

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

it will display

```
Â Â Â Â
```

instead of the four nbsp's

The list view looks like this,

```html
<section data-role="content">
  <h2>Home</h2>
  <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="a" data-filter="true">
    <li><a href="facebook.com">Acura</a></li>
    <li><a href="a">Audi</a></li>
    <li><a href="a">BMW</a></li>
    <li><a href="a">Cadillac</a></li>
    <li><a href="a">Ferrari</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

So my question is why would this be happening when there is another listview on another page working fine that looks identical.

```html
<section data-role="content">

  <h2>Company</h2>

  <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="a" data-filter="true">
    <li data-autodividers="true">Board</li>
    <li><a href="Matthew">Matthew  - CEO</a></li>
    <li><a href="Matthew">Bryner  - CFO</a></li>
    <li><a href="MatthewSa">Brian W - Board Member</a></li>
    <li data-autodividers="true">Full Time</li>
    <li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li>
    <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

heres an image of the A A A A
[image]

Comment: did you copy and paste from the jqm demo site? If so, delete all the spaces in the markup you copied. When you copy from the demo site, the &nbsp; is comming with the copied text.

Comment: @ezanker No spaces in the coding just did a double check, so it's not the issue

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already a few months old, and may not be relevant to the OP. But I found this post after trying to fix a similar issue for a couple hours.

Then I realized that "ezanker" is right. I just copy-pasted from the jqm demos, and had the same issue.

What happened was that the "&nbsp;" were added somehow between the tags but were not even visible in Dreamweaver. To fix the issue, remove ALL spaces and newlines between your tags:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-icon="false" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow" data-split-icon="gear">
          <li><h2>Item 1:</h2></li>
          <li><h2>Item 2:</h2></li>
          <li><h2>Item 3:</h2></li>
        </ul>
```

turns into:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-icon="false" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow" data-split-icon="gear"><li><h2>Item 1:</h2></li><li><h2>Item 2:</h2></li><li><h2>Item 3:</h2></li></ul>
```

See if that fixes the issue. Then reformat it by adding spaces and newlines in your editor again.